# Google cloud shell .customize_environment not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell, code-server

I'm trying to install code-server at the cloud shell boot,
so, I created the file .customize_environment

```
nano $HOME/.customize_environment
```

and the content is:

```
echo "installing code server..."
curl -fsSL https://code-server.dev/install.sh | sh
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
echo "code-server installed"
```

when the cloud shell starts it still prints the default message

```
Welcome to Cloud Shell! Type "help" to get started.
Your Cloud Platform project in this session is set to
```

rather than `installing code server...`, and doesn't install `code-server`.

Comment: Add this line to your script as the first line: `#!/bin/sh`. You might also need this change `export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH` (export + no quotes).

Answer (score 2):

this was caused by a bug that we are currently fixing.  If this issue persists through next week please reply back to this thread.

Comment: could you share the tracking number of the issue you mentioned in this answer (either in issue tracker or a link to the github issue)?

Comment: Thanks, @Luke Wood for your response. I will report the issue next week :)

Comment: This is fixed for anyone reading this in the future.