# .customize_environment failing for previously working apt-get update in cloud shell

Tags: google-cloud-shell

.customize_environment was failing and forcing me to boot as root (safe mode).

I've selectively recreated but even a simple apt-get update gets a bunch of errors like...

```
Err:1 http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-buster InRelease Temporary failure resolving 'packages.cloud.google.com'
```

Not sure if this is the root cause, I'm ultimately trying to..

```
apt-get install -y libxss1
apt-get install -y libgbm-dev
apt-get install -y parallel
```

In the meantime I'm having to manually run a whole bunch of installs which is getting pretty repetitive.

Comment: Interesting, the behavior is changing a little every time I reboot the cloud shell.  Generally something fails though, so sometimes it's bad enough that my dependencies are not installed correctly.  

Who knows, maybe it will fix itself miraculously.

Comment: Problem gone away as predicted by Luke.

Answer (score 1):

Normally customize_environment scripts cannot cause shell starts to failure.  Unfortunately there was a bug causing this to be possible.  The release containing the fix should be out in the next few days.

Would you mind trying to create the script again in a few days and letting me know if it works?

Thanks

Comment: I thought that might be the case from your comment on [Google cloud shell .customize_environment not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66480134/google-cloud-shell-customize-environment-not-working) but I couldn't see a follow up.  Thanks for clarifying.  Is it possible for you to actually post a comment here when the release is out, instead of me guessing?